# Making a questionnaire in LaTeX with sdaps

Tags: pdftex, questionnaire

I'm using sdaps to do a questionnaire but the package is a bit broken, maybe i'm not using it correctly but every optiongroup is broken and don't show the questions, can someone help me ?

It's supposed to do something like this
[image: Expected behavior]
but instead i get this
[image: What I have]

PS : pdflatex asks me if I want to continue because the package use a deprecated macro, how can I mute this ?

```tex
\documentclass[french]{sdapsclassic}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\PassOptionsToPackage{undo-recent-deprecations}{expl3}
\usepackage{sdapspdf}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\sdaps_context_append:nn{*}{pdf_form=true}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\author{The Author}
\title{Questionnaire}

\begin{document}
  \begin{questionnaire}
  \begin{Form}
    \addinfo{Date}{2021}

    \section{A Section}
    \begin{optiongroup}[vertical]{Please mark the next students}
      \choice[val=0]{0}
      \choice[val=1]{1}
      \choice[val=2]{2}
      \choice[val=3]{3}
      \choice[val=4]{4}
      \choice[val=5]{5}
      \choice[val=6]{6}
      \choice[val=7]{7}
      \choice[val=8]{8}
      \choice[val=9]{9}
      \choice[val=10]{10}

      \question[text=d1]{Henry}
      \question[text=d2]{Mary}
      \question[text=d3]{Alfred}
      \question[text=d4]{Smith}
    \end{optiongroup}
  \end{questionnaire}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: most people here wont have used the package (I'd never heard of it) but we could easily trace any errors if you provided in your question a small but complete document and showed exactly what errors  you got in code blocks in your question, so line endings are preserved

Comment: Thanks @david-carlisle I have updated my post

Comment: if you add the missing `\end{Form}` at the end and add `\cs_gset_protected:Npn \vbox_unpack_clear:N { \vbox_unpack_drop:N }` after ExplSyntaxOn then  [it looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74D9m.png) is that what you expect?

Comment: that was it thanks, how could i miss something that simple ^^

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You are missing an `\end{Form}`.  I'm not clear why the deprecation didn't get undone but you can re-instate the old name `\vbox_unpack_clear:N` using the code shown in l3deprecations.dtx so

```
\documentclass[french]{sdapsclassic}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\PassOptionsToPackage{undo-recent-deprecations}{expl3}
\usepackage{sdapspdf}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_gset_protected:Npn \vbox_unpack_clear:N { \vbox_unpack_drop:N }
\sdaps_context_append:nn{*}{pdf_form=true}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\author{The Author}
\title{Questionnaire}

\begin{document}
  \begin{questionnaire}
  \begin{Form}
    \addinfo{Date}{2021}

    \section{A Section}
    \begin{optiongroup}[vertical]{Please mark the next students}
      \choice[val=0]{0}
      \choice[val=1]{1}
      \choice[val=2]{2}
      \choice[val=3]{3}
      \choice[val=4]{4}
      \choice[val=5]{5}
      \choice[val=6]{6}
      \choice[val=7]{7}
      \choice[val=8]{8}
      \choice[val=9]{9}
      \choice[val=10]{10}

      \question[text=d1]{Henry}
      \question[text=d2]{Mary}
      \question[text=d3]{Alfred}
      \question[text=d4]{Smith}
    \end{optiongroup}
  \end{Form}
  \end{questionnaire}
\end{document}
```